# i have this two array and i have values i want to show data line by line like if i want to click on pushup at time it will shows pushup img &string

Tags: android, arrays, integer

```
public class Exerice_des extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout exerice_dec;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList =new ArrayList<>();
    Array arrayimage;
    Array arraydes;
  int ChestImage[] = {R.drawable.pushup,R.drawable.pullup,R.drawable.flatbenchpress,R.drawable.inclinedumbellpress,R.drawable.declinepress,R.drawable.inclinefly,R.drawable.chestdip,R.drawable.armbent};
    int Chestdes[]= {R.string.pushup,R.string.pullup,R.string.flatbench,R.string.incline,R.string.decline,R.string.inclinefly,R.string.chestdip,R.string.armbent};
```

}
}

i want to show this data in one by one

Answer (score 0):

Create a RecyclerView or ListView and the write a custom adapter for it.

To show the image on click either create a new activity or a custom dialog for it

For reference https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial